# How do I migrate data from an older Synology NAS to a newer one?

Tags: network-attached-storage, synology

I have just purchased a DS213j. I have an older single single bay unit that I would like to migrate the data from. Because the previous unit is a one bay, there is no official migration path. Synology support just pointed me to the [migration page](https://www.synology.com/en-us/knowledgebase/tutorials/484), which was not helpful.

I have a recent backup for the single bay unit on an external USB drive. I tried to attach it to the new unit and it doesn't even mount.

Is there some way that I can migrate my data?

Comment: What about the good old `rsync` or similar tools?

Comment: problem is that both the old unit and new cannot be on the network at the same time.

Comment: @mmcglynn Why? Perhaps there's a way to resolve that issue.

Comment: I didn't realize this question was so old. What was your solution?

Comment: There is no solution, other than manual copy or `rsync`.

Answer (score 1):

If using DSM's "Backup Destination" feature is out of the question (In DSM 5, its found in Main Menu -> Backup & Replication), then I would suggest 3 alternatives:

1. See if you can make something happen with [EZ Internet](https://www.synology.com/en-us/knowledgebase/tutorials/456).
2. If that isn't possible, then setup a port forward on the router in front of your NEW DS213j to that NAS, and then enable the 'Network Backup Destination' feature on that particular port on the NAS. Then, from the old NAS, just run rsync from the command line.
3. Use [Cloud Sync](https://www.synology.com/en-us/dsm/5.0/cloud_services).